# Hibernation time vs sleep time

Tags: sleep, power, hibernate

When you set the hibernation time on a laptop, this time is since the computer stayed still or since the computer went to sleep?

---

EX: If you set 1 minute to hibernation time and 5 minutes to sleep, the computer is going to hibernate 1 minute after you let it alone and sleep is gonna be skipped or 1 minute after it went to sleep?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I can't test it on my end, so I can't say for sure if this has changed, or that something on your end makes it work differently. There's no where on the internet that specifies this behavior or any other behavior for that matter. So its very possible that there is a certain order of events, and if one is before the other, the timer is from the previous event. Such as: monitor off, sleep, hibernation, etc. It can also be due to hybred sleep. But again, can't test it...

Answer (score 0):

If you set your laptop for 1 min hibernation and 5 minute sleep, your computer will never reach sleep mode. You'll want to set it the other way around. Then it'll go to sleep after 1 minute's idle time, give you another 4 minutes to do a quick wake-up (it's faster to recover from sleep mode than hibernation), and finally hibernate at the 5 minute mark.

Answer (score 0):

**Sleep**

The computer enters a low power mode that keeps everything in RAM but "pauses" execution of programs. Various things can wake the computer up from this state such as just about any interaction from hardware depending on settings.

**Hybrid Sleep**

The computer stores the contents of memory to the hard drive to prevent data loss but also leaves the contents in memory to allow resuming faster.

**Hibernate**

The computer stores the contents of memory to the hard drive and powers off. The only way to wake up from this would be through the computer's hardware. For instance, you can look in the BIOS/UEFI to see what can wake the computer up. Newer computers have systems such as Intel Active Management Technology that allows the computer to be woken up or put into low power states where updates and maintenance can be done. Wake-on-LAN, wake on keyboard/mouse, wake on network activity are all features that can be found in some BIOS/UEFIs that will wake a computer in hibernate.

*If the computer is set to hibernate, Windows is inactive and cannot be interacted with++. With that in mind, Windows won't be able to sleep since it's not running.* If Windows is sleeping, it's still powered on but in a "paused" state. Various things will bring the computer out of this state. Since Windows is still running, it can switch from this state into hibernation. For instance, you can configure Windows to bring itself out of sleep to perform Windows Updates.

*I believe Windows uses the same information to determine when the computer is idle so sleep and hibernate timers start at the same time. I can't find a source directly confirming this (see links 2 and 3).*

++ excluding out-of-band management such as some systems that Intel has among others

Sources:

1. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/difference-between-sleep-hybrid-sleep-and-hibernation-in-windows-7
2. (System Wake-up Events) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235(v=vs.85).aspx
3. (System sleep criteria) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373233(v=vs.85).aspx
4. (System sleeping states) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564575(v=vs.85).aspx
5. (System power states) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Although this answer does provide some nice information, it doesn't seem to actually answer the question.

Comment: @LPChip adjusted answer. Do you think that's better?

Comment: Before changing these settings I thought hibernation and sleep timers start at the same time, but what it shows me in the practice is that hibernation timer stars after the computer has gotten into sleep mode. Can somebody try to change the hibernation time and set it shorter than the sleep time and see if happen the same